# Как сделать качественное масштабирование изображений с текстом?

Tags: c#, .net, масштабирование

Подскажите, какие существуют способы качественного масштабирования изображений с текстом.

Пробовал так:

```
using (System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(imageBitmap)) {
    graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    graphics.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
    graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    graphics.DrawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0, width, height);
}

ImgBox.Source = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
    imageBitmap.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero,
    Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

Использовал Emgu CV:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> captureImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(imageBitmap);
Image<Bgr, byte> resizedImage = captureImage.Resize(width, height, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Area);

ImgBox.Source = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
    resizedImage.ToBitmap().GetHbitmap(),
    IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

Выводил так:

```
<Image x:Name="ImgBox" Width=".." Height=".." SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"/>
```

Но результата это нужного **не даёт** :(

Текст, если он есть на картинках, по-прежнему размывается или сильно рябит.

Для примера как мне нужно, приведу алгоритм TeamViewer.
Исходное изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат масштабирования:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Добавлю ещё вот какую тему: что если я имею не `Bitmap`, а `ID3D11Texture2D`? Как тут качественно "смаштабировать" **без преобразований** в другие типы (например, в тот же `Bitmap`)?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66689/discussion-on-question-by-d-stark--).

Answer (score 2):

Если графическая библиотека, которой Вы пользуетесь, не дает нужного результата, то попробуйте другую библиотеку. Например [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php). Там-же есть примеры использования и описание API к разным языкам программирования

Для сглаживания используется [antialiasing](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/antialiasing/).

Библиотека имеет достаточно простой API, хорошо документирована, может использоваться как в режиме командной строки (из скриптов) так и подключаться к исходному коду Ваших программам. Вот пример масштабирования на С++:

```
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 
using namespace Magick; 

int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{ 
    InitializeMagick(*argv);

    Image master("horse.jpg"); 
    Image second = master; 
    second.resize("640x480"); 
    Image third = master; 
    third.resize("800x600"); 
    second.write("horse640x480.jpg"); 
    third.write("horse800x600.jpg"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

У библиотеки ОЧЕНЬ много настроек и фильтров. Вот например фильтр unsharp, который увеличивает чёткость картинки: -unsharp 0.25x0.25+8+0.065.

Comment: Что-то не очень хорошо. Вернее намного хуже стандартных средств (C#): `MagickImage magickImage = new MagickImage(imageBitmap); magickImage.Quality = 100; magickImage.Resize(625, 500);`

Comment: При увеличении алиасинг и так не возникает. Наверное, это описка.

Comment: D .Stark@ вероятно, Вы пытаетесь получить результат там, где это недостижимо простыми средствами. Могу еще посоветовать глянуть статью на https://habrahabr.ru/post/261625/ - там много полезного по вопросам изменения размера изображений.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Делал не увеличение, а как раз уменьшение.

Comment: @bigov Так статья по сути об уменьшении "веса" изображений, а не о мастабировании (там немного есть конечно).

Comment: @bigov Вы могли бы продемонстрировать в ответе работу с библиотекой на C# - пример уменьшения размеров изображения с текстом в 2 раза?

Comment: Важно то видите, чтобы текст оставался читаемым при масштабировании.

Comment: @D .Stark я работаю под Linux, c Шарпом увы не знаком, да и не дело это - кодить за кого-то. Что касается масштабирования шрифтов, то с "обычной" картинкой красиво не получится - есть такая проблема. В таких случах пользуются специально подготовленными изображениями: https://habrahabr.ru/post/282191/